# addToolTipRect, but where is "modifyToolTipRect"

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-design-patterns

My view changed sizes, the relative graphical elements i have tooltips for have changed location. Do I really have to remove each tooltip and add again with the new rect? or is there some "modifyToolTipRect" somewhere. I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you must remove and recreate them each time your view's geometry changes.